# LibGDX GUI Texture Packer won't open

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

I downloaded the LibGDX texture packer from here: https://github.com/crashinvaders/gdx-texture-packer-gui

but I can't figure out how to open it. I ran the gradlew and it said build successful but how do I open it? This isn't the command line version, but the GUI version but there's no jar to run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download build of [gdx-texture-packer-gui](https://github.com/crashinvaders/gdx-texture-packer-gui/releases) and run in your system.

If you're Window user you can download [.exe](https://github.com/crashinvaders/gdx-texture-packer-gui/releases/download/4.4.0/gdx-texturepacker-4.4.0.exe) file else if you're Mac user download [.dmg](https://github.com/crashinvaders/gdx-texture-packer-gui/releases/download/4.4.0/gdx-texturepacker-4.4.0.dmg) file.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I downloaded the source files instead :P